# After Linksys WRT3200ACM setup, no Wifi

Tags: router

I installed a brand new Linksys WRT3200ACM. I can use it fine with RJ45.

The note says that after set up I should see the two bands wifi SSID.

But I don't. During startup phase, at some point I see the two wifi band lights on for a short while. But when it is finished starting, I don't see any Wifi SSID from other computers.

The troubling shooting in the doc doesn't address this case. Not sure if there is something wrong with the new router.

I am doing a basic startup on this new router, nothing fancy.

**EDIT**

1. Have you tried a 30/30/30 Reset?
   I am not familiar with this reset. What I did is just plug it in. Since I was not seeing any WIFI network, I reset it (without allowing automatic firmware upgrade), and I still could not see Wifi networks
2. I haven't allow automatic software updates so I don't know if one was done anyway at the first boot? I wouldn't think so.

3.
4. this is the note I have been using, and the trouble shooting paragraph doesn't address my problem: [Manual](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/WRT3200ACM__UG_International.pdf)

5. Have you confirmed the wireless capabilities are enabled? Yes, I saw from the interface on 192.168.1.1 that the two bands Wifis are enabled. Internet works fine when I use an RJ45. As I said, the 2 wifi lights goes briefly on during startup phase.

**EDIT 2**

I did the 30-30-30 and allowed automatic updates (it didn't detect any). It doesn't behave the same now. I can only see the 5Gz Wifi net from Windows10 and connect to it. I see none from Ubuntu and Android.
To see if it makes a difference, I disabled the 2.4Gz. No change.
Here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: I require a couple clarifications.  1) Have you tried a 30/30/30 Reset?  2). Have you updated to the current firmware?  3) What note?  4) What document?  5). Have you confirmed the wireless capabilities are enabled?  All clarification should be provided in the form of an edit to your question

Comment: I edited to answer your questions, thank you for taking the time to help me solve my issue.

Comment: I should definitely see your SSIDs. You should double check your configuration, even though you just plugged it in. Can we see a screenshot, please? You should also upgrade the firmware, it's dangerous not to.

Comment: [Make sure the 2.4 and 5.0 GHz networks are turned on](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/WRT3200ACM__UG_International.pdf#page18).  Update the firmware to the current version.  30/30:30 Reset is holding the Reset buttons down for 30 seconds, while continuing to hold the reset button unplugging the power for 30 seconds, then holding it down for 30 seconds while you plug it back in.  Provide screenshots of your configuration as illustrated on page 18.  Do all of this after you update the firmware.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon for a Linksys device to be dead out of the box. Even the Linksys small business series have a high DOA rate. I would say it's about 1 in 10 that I have seen on deployments. I personally would just follow the factory instructions, if the radios don't turn on... Seek a replacement, it's most likely defective.

Comment: I edit (edit2) after doing 30-30-30. The behaviour is different now

Comment: @BobYoplait - So the reset worked.  At least you have 5.0 Ghz band working.  Just to confirm you are running 1.0.6.186168?

Comment: This is indeed this version that is running. It seems there is a config change to do on the router because Macs, IPhones, some Android8 see vnc5, but not some other Android8, Ubuntu. Are you aware of what I need to change such that all devices see vnc5 network ? Your guess is 2.4Ghz band is broken ?

Comment: actually, my Ubuntu machines have Realtek RTL8723BE wifi card that are 2.4GHz only. Same for Samsung A3 phones. That's why

Comment: next, I'll see with a "wifi analyzer" app if my router 2.4GHz band is not masked by another router and if I should change channels.

Comment: OK, I activated the 2.4Ghz band, applied the config, restarted the router, I am running "wifi analyzer" and I don't see my 2.4GHz access point, even for very low SNR (-88dBm). What should I do next ?

Comment: going on channel 11 with 20MHz bandwidth, that made it

Comment: @BobYoplait - You should submit an answer to your question.